# Resizing browser window disturbs page flow

Tags: html, css

I have applied css to my page and it looks good when the browser is maximized, but whenever I reduce the size of the browser window the flow of the elements are getting disturbed:

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rTjyV/**

My code is as follows:

**CSS**

```
body{
   background:#eff3f6;
   border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
}
.content{margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:200px;
    margin-left:200px;
    background:#fefefe;}
.box
{
    background:#fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
    border-top:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 1px;
    color:#444;
    font:normal 12px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    margin:0 auto 30px ;
    width:auto;
}
.box.login
{
    height:260px;
    width:332px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-130px 0 0 -166px;
}
.boxBody
{
    background:#fefefe;
    border-top:1px solid #dde0e8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dde0e8;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.box footer
{
    background:#eff4f6;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    padding:22px 26px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:32px;
}
.box label
{
    display:block;
    font:14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    margin:10px 0 0 6px;
}
.box footer label{
    float:left;
    margin:4px 0 0;
}
.box footer input[type=checkbox]{
    vertical-align:sub;
    *vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box input[type=text],
.box input[type=password],
.txtField, textarea,
.cjComboBox,select
{
    border:6px solid #F7F9FA;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
    margin:3px 0 4px;
    padding:8px 6px;
    width:270px;
    display:inline;
}
.box input[type=text]:focus,
.box input[type=password]:focus,
.txtField:focus, textarea:focus,
.cjComboBox:focus, select:focus
{
    border:6px solid #f0f7fc;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) inset, 0 0 1px #0d6db6 inset;
    color:#333;
}
.cjComboBox, select
{
    width:294px;
}
.cjComboBox.small, select.small
{
    padding:3px 2px 3px 6px;
    width:100px;
    border-width:3px !important;
}
.txtField.small,textarea:small
{
    padding:3px 6px;
    width:200px;
    border-width:3px !important;
}

.rLink{padding:0 6px 0 0; font-size:11px; float:right;}
.box a{color:#999;}
.box a:hover, .box a:focus{text-decoration:underline;}
.box a:active{color:#f84747;}
.btnLogin
{
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:#a1d8f0;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #badff3, #7acbed);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#badff3), to(#7acbed));
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#badff3', EndColorStr='#7acbed')";
    border:1px solid #7db0cc !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:11px 16px;
    font:bold 11px/14px Verdana, Tahomma, Geneva;
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0px; 
    color:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0 1px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px 1px;
    margin-left:12px;
    float:right;
    padding:7px 21px;
}

.btnLogin:hover,
.btnLogin:focus,
.btnLogin:active{
    background:#a1d8f0;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #7acbed, #badff3);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7acbed), to(#badff3));
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#7acbed', EndColorStr='#badff3')";
}
.btnLogin:active
{
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 -1px 0px; 
}
footer#main{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font:normal 11px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
}
menuli{
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: none;


    float: none;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: none;
    text-align: none;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;



    width: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" align="center"
    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#63B8FF">
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="justify"><img
                src="/traineeApp/images/Yell.jpg"
                style="float: left; position: relative;" alt="Yell Adworks"
                title="Yell Adworks" height="50px" /></td>
            <td width="30%" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
                <h2>
                    <font color=#ffffff >Trainning Information&nbsp;System</font>
                </h2>
            </td >

            <td width="30%" align="center" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: bottom;">Welcome,&nbsp;&nbsp;!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
                href="/traineeApp/logout.htm"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Logout</span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<div class="content" >
<div id="content" style="position:absolute;">
<div id="navigation" >
    <div id="nav-lt-curve"><img src="/traineeApp/css/blue-images/blue-lt-curve.png" alt="" width=auto; height="50" /></div>

  <div id="navigation-mid" style="width: auto;">
    <ul style="width: auto;" id="nav">
        <li style="width: 175px; background:none;"><a href="/traineeApp/DashBoard/dashBoard.htm">DashBoard</a></li>
        <li style="width: 170px; background:none;"><a href="/traineeApp/CreateTraining/training.htm">Create Training</a></li>
        <li style="width: 170px; background:none;"><a href="/traineeApp/CreateFeedBack/feedback.htm">Create FeedBack</a></li>
        <li style="width: 170px; background:none;"><a href="/traineeApp/JasperReports/reports.htm">Reports</a></li>
        <li style="width: 164px; background:none; display: inline;"><a href="/traineeApp/Customized/customizedproperties.htm">Options</a>


        </li></ul>
   </div>
<div id="nav-rt-curve">
    <img src="/traineeApp/css/blue-images/blue-rt-curve.png" alt="" width="14" height="50" />
</div>
  </div>
  </div>

<br /><br /><br />



<form id="commonBean" action="submit.htm" method="post">

                <div class="content" align="center">
                <div class="box">
                    <br>
                    <h2>
                        <label>Training Creation</label></h2>
                        <label>(<span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span> Mandatory Fields)</label>

                    <hr>

                        <table>

                        <tr><td>

                        <label><span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span>Training Name: </label>
                        </td><td>
                        <input id="trainingName" name="trainingName" type="text" value=""/>
                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                        </td></tr>


                        <tr><td>
                        <label><span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span>Training Type: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <select id="trainingtype" name="trainingtype">
                            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="internal">Internal</option>

                            <option value="External">External</option>
                        </select>
                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>

                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <label><span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span>Department Name: </label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <select id="departmentName" name="departmentName"><option value="">--Select--</option>
                         </select>
                    <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <label>Trainer Name: </label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <select id="trainerName" name="trainerName"><option value="">--Select--</option>


                     --%>
                        </select>
                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <label>Group Name: </label>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <select id="group" name="group"><option value="">--Select--</option>
                         </select>
                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <label><span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span>Starting Date: </label>

                        </td><td>
                        <input id="trFrom" name="trFrom" type="text" value=""/>
                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <label><span style="font-style: italic;color: red;">*</span>Ending Date: </label>
                        </td><td>
                        <input id="trEnd" name="trEnd" type="text" value=""/>

                        <span style="font-style: italic;color: red;"></span>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                    </table>
                <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnLogin" style="align:center; float:none;"/>
            <input type="button" value="Reset" class="btnLogin" style="align:center; float:none;" onclick="window.location.href='training.htm'"/>
            <br><br>    
            </div>

    </div>
</form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The CSS is disturbed in what way? When you say minimize, do you mean reduce the browser dimensions - or do you actually mean minimize the browser? Also, please include HTML and not the JSP markup - I know some of the people on here are more efficient than computers but I don't think any of them are actually computers who visually render templates when sent to their view. If you can provide a link to the broken page or reproduce the issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then you should get faster, more accurate answers.

Comment: yes sir when i reduce the dimension it gets disturbed... you can see in jsp that i have applied that particular class selector to the div selection.. thats it.. nothing special i did in jsp.. its as simple as html itself

Comment: I understand that, but this is a community site where someone might have the same problem with a PHP or C# rendered page. If you provide the HTML then this question will become relevant to them aswell. The problem has nothing to do with Spring, but rather the CSS and HTML.

Comment: Also, if you cannot provide a link then providing the HTML will at least allow anyone trying to answer this question to reproduce your page in a sandbox environment and view the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @mukund - the main problem lays with the CSS for `.content` and the way that you have tried to center it.

Try changing your CSS to the following instead:

```
body{
  background:#eff3f6;
  border: 1px solid #C3D4DB;
  text-align: center;   /* added this to center any children */
}

.content{
    margin-top:1px;
    display: inline-block;  /* this is key */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    background:#fefefe;
}
```

Note: `*display: inline;` and `*zoom: 1;` are added for IE7 support

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wR2FL/**

Comment: Hey thank you @mukund and thanks My Head Hurts. . with minimum changes i acheived...

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your css like:

1) I guess you want to align your div.content in the middle of browser
   and hence

```
 margin-right:200px;  
 margin-left:200px;
```

It is not the standard way, rather do like this:

```
 body{  
 background:  
 border:  
 ..........  
 margin:0 auto;  
 text-align:center;  
 }  
 .content{  
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:5px;  

//don't include margin-left or margin-right instead set a width for the div  

  width:800px;  
  .............  
  }
```

And according to the width set for the div.content set the width of other elements.....

Comment: Hi @mukund , can you please suggest any way to prevent from webpage broken condition , what i have to do .